# Need to insert in products table from more than one tables with dynamic user id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables **users**, **products** and **temp_table**. i have imported an xlsx file having 1,00,000 records in to **temp_table**. now i have to insert these records to **products** table. and here i have to save user_id from **users** table to **products** table as well.
Note: user_id is dynamic(i.e. in xlsx file there is a column called email and I have created a new user for their email). so in **products** table user_id will be dynamically inserted.
I have used below query, but it is taking too much time. and sometimes my MySQL get locked.

```
INSERT INTO products
        (user_id,
        brand_id,
        points_discount,
        amount,
        sub_total,
        added_on)
        SELECT users.user_id, 
            brand_id,
            discount,
            amount,
            sub_total,
            added_on
        FROM temp_table
        INNER JOIN users 
        ON email = users.email;
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: how is this question related to Laravel? :)

Comment: I'm integrating it with Laravel. but for now, I have checked it with MySQL.

Comment: @Sachem He tried to ask that can we do this using laravel?

Comment: is there any solution to remove join but include user_id in products table dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index on `email` column of `temp_table` and `users` tables.
Also ensure both the columns have same `datatype`

```
ALTER TABLE temp_table ADD KEY `idx_email` (`email`);

ALTER TABLE users ADD KEY `idx_email` (`email`);
```

Comment: I have made changes but there is no impact on timing.
my main concern is timing. it should process fast.

Comment: strange. the indexes should greatly improve the speed. maybe try adding user_id column to temp_table and populate it with UPDATE query first, then do simple INSERT ... SELECT ... without a join?

Comment: Yes, but again, if I'm going to update user_id in temp_table. there will be time issue. because i have to check whether email is equal to both table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an [artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#writing-commands) for this, which queries a given number of records from the `temp_table` (where I'd add a `processed` flag/column with boolean value) and either schedule this to run once each minute or run it from the terminal by yourself. Like query 10000-20000 entries/run (maybe more, depends on the server and environment) and process it.

Comment: It is not a big deal. If you open this page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#writing-commands, you will find a detailed, step by step description, and you will be able to write it much faster, than me without any database and such.